# CodeIgniter .htaccess issue www and non-www urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a website developed in CodeIgniter HMVC. I am using **https** protocol.

I want to use only non-www urls, https://seocompany.us.com

If some one try to use https://www.seocompany.us.com, it should redirect to https://seocompany.us.com

Here is my `.htaccess` code that works fine, if I use https://seocompany.us.com/services but adds `index.php` if I type https://www.seocompany.us.com/services and redirect to https://seocompany.us.com/index.php?/services

```
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seocompany.us.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue, based on @Tpojka's work. I am sharing my solution here.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking if request is made over secure scheme port or not. You are not checking for subdomain prefix. Try this way:

```
RewriteBase /

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# force non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seocompany\.us\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://seocompany.us.com/$1 [R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also clear the browser cache or try it from other browser / private window.

Comment: This is not working, I type this url: http://seocompany.us.com/seo-web-design, and it doesn't redirect to https://seocompany.us.com/seo-web-design.

Comment: I made some changes, try now.

Comment: Same issue. No change. I tried in chrome & firefox privacy mode.

Comment: Have you set your `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` values for base url and index page (first two values)?

Comment: Yes. All settings are okay.